# when using mean crease on subdivision modifier it makes the edge straight the way it should, but it goes over it and negates the crease

Tags: modeling, modifiers, edit-mode, subdivision-surface, topology

as the title says, I have modelled an object using a subdivision surface modifier, and I need  some of the edges to be straight. For that I have used a combination of some crude control edges, but mostly using a mean crease to define the edges I want straight. This works for all cases except for the corners, here it look like it works, but then the modifier goes over the edge and smoothes it out, which is not what I want. See picture below.

[image]

and this is how it looks from above

[image]

and this is what I want it to look like

[image]

and this is the topology view(note that this happens in multiple places, but all have similar geometry to this one)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Either mark this oblique edge as well (1) or remove the support edge loop (2):

[image]